# how to render a form using JSON in JQuery Form builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have simple web application where i can create forms and save its JSON in a database then get the same JSON and Render it back , all built using the Jquery FormBuilder that is available online. Right Now , I am Struggling with render part because it doesnt display anything , and my knowledge in java script is pretty limited to fix it .

here is what i have done so far

for the PHP side , i can take the Json schema and give it to a variable , i tested it and the value is there and can be printed

```
$json=$row['survey_schema'];
```

for the java script part

```
var container = $('#formrender');var options = {
container,
dataType:'json',
formData:'<?php $json ?>' }; container.formRender(options);
```

as for the HTML

```
<div id="formrender"></div>
```

from what i understand the script looks for the div named formrender and renders the form based on the provided JSON that i gave it to it .
but nothing happens and it is just a blank screen

thank you , and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available in jQuery Form builder documentation, and this is how I did it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-render.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery($ => {
        const escapeEl = document.createElement("textarea");
        const code = document.getElementById("formrender");
        const formData = "";//Your JSON data goes here
        const addLineBreaks = html => html.replace(new RegExp("><", "g"), ">\n<");

        // Grab markup and escape it
        const $markup = $("<div/>");
        $markup.formRender({ formData });

        // set < code > innerText with escaped markup
        code.innerHTML = addLineBreaks($markup.formRender("html"));

        hljs.highlightBlock(code);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work . i echo out the json in the form data and nothing

Comment: are you useing this link https://formbuilder.online/ ?? If you are then you have to set the json data in specific way. you can check the demo data here https://formbuilder.online/docs/formRender/options/render/ .

Comment: the problem isnt the json i think , i even copy and pasted their own example . it only creates a text area with the json inside it rather than rending the form

Comment: follow the documentation it will solve the issue. or give me your email I will send your an working example .

Comment: thank you , i did solve it with your example but i had some typo in the html which prevented it from rendring